# ¿Cómo convertir un Array en Objeto?

Tags: javascript

Me dan una **función** que recibe como parámetro una **Queue de array** que contiene nombres de películas, a las que tengo que **guardar** en un **objeto** y devolverlo. La función es esta:

```
function guardarPeliculas(pelisQueue){}
```

Aquí mi **array** pelisQueue:

```
pelisQueue =['Morbius', 'La invitación', 'Halloween: el final', 'Muerte en el Nilo', 'Black Adam']
```

Me pide que el objeto contenedor tiene que tener las propiedades con números **ascendentes** desde el 1 (1, 2, 3, etc...), exceptuando la ***primera*** propiedad que tiene el nombre *estrenar*; quedaría así:

```
  OUTPUT --> { "estrenar": 'Morbius', 1: 'La invitación', 2: 'Halloween: el final', 3:'Black Adam' }
```

Y otra cosa más: a medida que guarda las películas, tengo que **quitarla** de la Queue y tengo que respetar el orden **FIFO.**

Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
function guardarPeliculas(pelisQueue) { 
  var u = Object.assign({},pelisQueue)
 return u
  }
```

En teoría tiene que funcionar, creo, pero no me lo pasa.

Comment: No es posible tener ese OUTPUT con un objeto, las propiedades del tipo Number van primero siempre.  Tendrías que una un Map, es posible usar esta colección para tu ejercicio?

Comment: Si se puede tener ese output en un objeto, la llave del objeto puede ser tanto entero como string

Comment: @JorgeAlmada No es posible el OUTPUT, la clave "estrenar" nunca será impresa en primer lugar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fácilmente puedes recorrer el array y agregar cada elemento a un nuevo objeto, y éste será llamado **`pelisQueueObj`**. Recuerda que al recorrer el array, estamos recorriendo a partir del segundo elemento, ya que el primer elemento será asignado en una nueva clave del objeto (llamado **`estrenar`**).

Ojo que el objeto ordena por defecto que las claves numéricas vayan primero y las alfabéticas al final, es por ello que la clave **`estrenar`** irá al último.

---

**Ejemplo:**

```js
let pelisQueue = ['Morbius', 'La invitación', 'Halloween: el final', 'Muerte en el Nilo', 'Black Adam'];
let pelisQueueObj = {};

pelisQueueObj["estrenar"] = pelisQueue[0];

for (let i = 1; i < pelisQueue.length; i++) {
  pelisQueueObj[i] = pelisQueue[i];
}

console.log(pelisQueueObj);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Si es necesario que se quite de la queue, una buena forma en la que se podría asignar sería llenando un objeto, usando un while que revise si la queue todavía tiene elementos dentro, el elemento que llegue se lo asigne al objeto, lo saque, y aumente un contador que es el que asignará la llave al objeto

```js
const pelisQueue = ['Morbius', 'La invitación', 'Halloween: el final', 'Muerte en el Nilo', 'Black Adam']
let objectResult = {}
let counter = 0;

while(pelisQueue.length){
    if(counter === 0){
    objectResult.estrenar = pelisQueue[0]
  } else{
    objectResult[counter] = pelisQueue[0]
  }
  counter++
  pelisQueue.shift()
}

console.log(objectResult)
console.log(pelisQueue)
```

Comment: Me sirve, gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Dado que el ejercicio parece ser irresoluble (al menos para mi pobre intelecto), dejo una versión alternativa a las propuestas, creando un objeto dentro de otro, al externo le carga la primer película, y el interno las siguientes, quitando con **shift** las peliculas del array original (shift quita el primer elemento).

```js
const pelisQueue = ['Morbius', 'La invitación', 'Halloween: el   final', 'Muerte en el Nilo', 'Black Adam']
pelisQueueObj = {};
obj = {};

function guardarPeliculas( pelisQueue ) { 
  pelisQueueObj[ "estrenar" ] = pelisQueue.shift();
  pelisQueueObj[ "otras" ] = obj;
  orden = 0;
  while( pelisQueue.length ) {   
    obj[ "" + orden] = pelisQueue.shift();        
    orden++;
  }
  return obj;
}

guardarPeliculas( pelisQueue );

console.log( pelisQueueObj )
console.log( pelisQueueObj.otras[1] )
console.log( pelisQueueObj.estrenar )
console.log( pelisQueue )
```

Comment: pero... y el objeto?...

Comment: @Cris223511.dev, buena pregunta, error imperdonable el mio, descarto respuesta, gracias por la observación.